# Passing json data to other screen for specific item

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to pass the data from List, which i currently load into a Dropdown-Menu, to other screen.
I know how to pass data by using Materialpagebuilder and context.

But how to send only json data for selected item from dropdown menu.

For example:

```
[
 {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 100,
    "title": "at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum",
    "body": "cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\nipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\nautem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\naccusamus ratione error aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 98,
    "title": "laboriosam dolor voluptates",
    "body": "doloremque ex facilis sit sint culpa\nsoluta assumenda eligendi non ut eius\nsequi ducimus vel quasi\nveritatis est dolores"
  },
]
```

Lets say i selected id: 98!
How can i pass only the data (userId, id, title, body) for this to the other screen.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class call user and use an object with all this variables and then pass the object corresponding to the selected item.

```
MaterialButton(
  color: Colors.green.shade200,
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => DetailOfTheUser(selectedUser,)
    ));
  },
  child: Text("Details"),
),
```